# What's the probleem [SCILAB]

Tags: runtime-error, scilab

I'm trying to run this program but, he does not want to show the result.

here is the program:

```
t=0:5:40
if a==2.22
    v(t)=a*t
else 
    v(t)=0
end
disp(v,'v=')
```

:((((

Comment: Your example is incomplete : Variable a  is not defined. Also be aware that v(t) will raise an arror as t has a zero and array are indexed from 1 in Scilab.

Answer (score 1):

You've made two errors:

1. Accessing an array at 0:
   Since `t` is vector of constant from 0 to 40 with a step of 5,`v(t)` means that you're tring to access to the 0-th element of v. I assume that you want `v(i)` to be `a*t(i)` for all `i` so juste write `v=a*t`
2. `v` is either a scalar or a vector:  I assume you want `v` to be vector the same size of `t`. So `v=0` should be `v=zeros(t)`.

The resulting code is

```
t=0:5:40;
if a==2.22
  v=a*t;
else 
  v=zeros(t);
end;
disp(v,'v=');
```